# open and monitor window running flash app without browser

Tags: java

My goal is to open a new window running a flash app from an url (http://curvefever.com/CF_Preloader.swf), and be able to interact with it with java, and do things like take screenshots of the content, and invoke keypresses.

while I could achieve this by opening the flash app in a browser and monitor the browser with selenium (and using an awt robot to take screenshots), I am looking for a better method because I want to avoid the extra lag brought with running the browser, but also because other windows might obstruct the screenshots when the browser window is in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I think Selenium is still a good choice for manipulating the Flash application.

You can use the WebDriver's built in screenshot ability, which only captures the browser, so you won't have to worry about other windows obstructing the one you want to capture.

[Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I have tried this method with all the output types, but I am not able to reach the desired framerate. With awt robot, I manage to get a framerate up to 10, by using selenium, with all the 3 output types I get framerates around 7. :(